# no suitable method found to override C# when i call ToString

Tags: c#, windows

**Why when I use this class(called TaxiStation) which is calls toString of Taxi Class:**

```
public override string TaxiInformation(int i)
        {

            return taxiCollectionDrivers[i].ToString();

        }
```

ToString() of Taxi class:

```
public override string ToString()
        {
     string str;
     str = "Taxi ID: " + this.taxiId + "\nDriver Name: " + this.driverName + "\nPassengers " + this.numPass + "\nTotal Passengers: " + totalPassengers + "\nRate Per Kilometer: " + this.ratePerKilometer+
         "\n\n Available: " + this.available ; 
     return str;    
        }
```

It's show me the error no suitable method found to override? how do i solve it ?

Comment: what is relation between `TaxiStation` and `Taxi` ?

Comment: the relation between them that TaxiStation has in there's Taxies ( Taxi is class for one taxi,stationTaxi class collect them all).

Comment: acording to your comment, I would say you can not use `override` in this case. Look on my answer.

Comment: What is `TaxiStation` inheriting from? My guess is that you just need to remove the `override` keyword on the `TaxiInformation(int i)` method.

Comment: What is the declaration of Taxi class?

Comment: Try the following: public new String ToString(){ ... } However, I think there's either another error in your code or Taxi's base seals ToString().

Answer (score 1):

I just **suppose**, considering that the message written can not be related to `ToString(..)` override, as it present in parent of all objects in `CLR`, in `object`, so I **suppose** it's all about

```
public override string TaxiInformation(int i){
   ....
}
```

method. To be able *override* a method you have to have in the **base** class of the type where this method is overridden the same method (same signature) declared like `virtual` or `abstract`.

An hypothetic example:

```
public class TaxiStation
{
  ..... 
    public virtual string TaxiInformation(int i){
       ....
    }

}


public class Taxi : TaxiStation 
{
    public override string TaxiInformation(int i){
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The override modifier is required to extend or modify the **abstract** or **virtual** implementation of an inherited method, property, indexer, or event.
>
> ...
>
> The overridden base method **must have the same signature as the override method**.

[MSDN: override (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)

For example:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
   public abstract void Foo(int i);
}
```

or

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
   public virtual void Foo(int i)
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

Another reason that a method is not available for overriding is because it has been marked as **[sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx)** in the base class:

```
public class ClassA // Inherited from object
{
    public sealed override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    // Compilation error!
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString();
    } 
}
```

Comment: The sealed keyword produces a different Error in my VS2010 GER. It explicitly complains about the base being sealed. However, this one is the only one that makes sense to me. @XxYo0nixX do you get any additional errors? Could be caused by a previous error.